# MapView showing blank view with google icon on it when ejected from expo

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-maps, mapview

So i built an app in expo where i use `MapView` and it worked fine until i ejected from expo.

It showed map correctly but when i ejected from expo, it shows a blank view with google icon on it.

Note that API key is right and has android maps sdk enabled and is also present in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

I also tried some solutions like changing `android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"` to `android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"` (just saw it from github issues  but i don't understand it. Please explain it too).

Answer (score 0):

I guess this because you are using debug key so it will work while you are connecting to use it in the same way you want I guess you need to have a release API key

Comment: Tried with both. Still can you please show how to get them.